# how do i generate texts and comparing a specific text on its own

Tags: java

I do not know how to work on the following problem (How can I print each letter of the entered word at the end of each randomly generated word and the single letter of the entered word can be repeated more than once and take the letters from the entered word randomly while ensuring that all the letters of the entered word are taken And print them out)

**Example:**

input:

`name = "adel"`

output:

```
lkjljl a                     
sdada l               
lkkjlkj l               
werwrew d           
oioiu e
```

---

What I have so far:

```
public void Gen(String name) {
    Random r = new Random();
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int j = 0; j < name.length(); j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())) % 30; i++) {
            System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
        }
        char g = name.charAt(j);
        System.out.println(g);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sounds like a homework task! :)  Please ask a very specific question rather than asking for a complete solution.

Comment: The question is very confusing

Comment: What if `name` is not made of unique characters? For example "Adelle". Does it have to guess `l` twice or is one time enough?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your example. Shouldn't the first **output** line for **input** `adel` be `l` instead of `lkjljl a` (because the computer guessed a letter of your name - `l` - on its first attempt?

Comment: the computer guesses the string from Alphabet variable and prints the string from the alphabet plus a random char from the name variable.
every time generate a string from alphabet variable should end with a char from name variable

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you want to do. The [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61923960/1) was much more clear. But that description doesn't match with the example in [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61923960/1).

Comment: Sorry, but I am weak in the English language.
the first revision was written by my friend

Answer (score 0):

In your second `for` loop,

```
for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())) % 30; i++)
```

`alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length()))` gives you `String`, not `int`, so there's an error there. You can just remove `alphabet.charAt()`.

Also, On your `print` statement, it generate another random number, which can be different than the one in the second `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Gen(String name) {
    Random r = new Random();
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int j = 0; j < name.length(); j++) 
        {
            System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));

              char g = name.charAt(j);
           System.out.println(g);
        }



}
```